# Can we use offline google maps in java desktop application?

Tags: java, google-maps

I want to know if there is a way to have "google maps" embedded "in a java desktop application in offline mode"? I want user to be able to zoom in and zoom out in the maps. And the application will accept source and destination from the user depending on which the map should appear. I have implemented it using online mode by signing in to google, obtaining API key and all. But i now wonder if it is possible offline.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know concept of offline maps ? Exactly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: If it is offline, where would it get the map data from? Do you plan to cache the Earth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately an offline Google map is not allowed under their [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1_3).